# Is it wise to get engaged in several programming languages or to master only the one I got experience already

Tags: web-applications, frameworks, programming-languages

There have emerged a lot of languages and frameworks for web development and it is almost impossible to catch up with everything. I am experienced programmer in Asp.Net for years and never learned other web programming languages and frameworks. For example, I am curious about Ruby on Rails and would like to learn about it.

I believe that experience in different languages would give me a valuable insight toward web development.  For example, as a developer who only used  asp.net controls in my life, when I begin to use html controls and learn jQuery and Ajax, I never used asp.net controls again, and I learned a lot from this experience. However, I feel like there is no end to it, and maybe it is better to just focus on one thing. Because, even that one thing can get really complicated enough (asp.net web api, MVC, entity framework, signalR, angularjs, knockoutjs etc.)

Is it better to stay in my comfort zone mastering what I have experienced so far, or is it better to get out and discover new stuff? I am asking this as someone who does programming just for personal purposes not planning to work in a company.

I hope I am not asking a stupid question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never stick to one thing, It will never help you in the long run. Although you feel comfortable with what you know, doing things outside of your comfort zone is always great. Keeping up with the new stuff will keep your work modern, more advanced, and better overall.

I wouldn't give up what you are comfortable with though since it is always a good foundation.

Go out and learn something new! You won't regret it!

Comment: Agree. Imagine being an expert Flash developer 5 years ago, knowing *only* Flash. Specific languages and especially frameworks are a fleeting thing, it's best to have a broad knowledge of multiple things.